# Why does the same spark program runs well on spark-shell but fails & ends with exit status 1

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run a pyspark program by using spark-submit:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE = 'net.snowflake.spark.snowflake'

def get_records(spark:SparkSession):
    sfOptions = {
        'sfURL' : 'url',
        'sfAccount' : 'acntname',
        'sfUser' : 'username',
        'sfPassword' : 'pwd',
        'sfRole' : 'role',
        'sfDatabase' : 'dbname',
        'sfSchema' : 'schema',
        'sfWarehouse' : 'warehousename'
    }
    rec_df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE).options(**sfOptions).options('query','select AREA from SCHEMA.TABLENAME limit 1').load()
    rec_df.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        spark = SparkSession.Builder.master('yarn').appName('Check_Con').getOrCreate()
        sc = SparkContext("yarn", "Simple App")
        spark = SQLContext(sc)
        spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('CHECK')
        get_records(spark)
```

Spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --keytab /home/devuser/devuser.keytab --principal devuser@PRINCIPAL.COM --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 1G --jars /home/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.8.0-spark_2.4.jar,/home/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.9.jar --files /home/devuser/conn_props/core-site_dummy.xml,/home/devuser/conn_props/hdfs-site_dummy.xml check_snow.py
```

When I submit the code, it ends with `ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1`
There is no error description or anything as such. The job just ends abruptly.

```
20/07/17 19:12:42 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1
20/07/17 19:12:42 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
20/07/17 19:12:42 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
```

I tried to pass the core-site.xml & hdfs-site.xml in the spark-submit command as well. But no changes are working.

If I submit the same code on the terminal, on spark-shell, the code runs well. I am working in spark for the last one year faced many exceptions but never this one. I don't understand this phenomenon.

Edit 1:
Some of the suggestions were to remove the unwanted part in the code and also remove setting of yarn inside the code since it is being set in spark-submit.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        spark = SparkSession.Builder.appName('Check_Con').getOrCreate()
        get_records(spark)
```

Even after that, I still see the same exception.

Could anyone let me know if I had made any mistake and how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --keytab /home/devuser/devuser.keytab --principal devuser@PRINCIPAL.COM --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 1G --jars /home/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.8.0-spark_2.4.jar,/home/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.9.jar --files /home/devuser/conn_props/core-site_dummy.xml,/home/devuser/conn_props/hdfs-site_dummy.xml check_snow.py --verbose` will see the any other trace we get.

Answer (score 0):

`exit code: 13` failure is due to the multiple `spark,SparkContext, SparkConf Initializations` and misconfigurations between `local` and `yarn`, so the YARN AppMaster is throwing an exit code 13.

please comment out the following section and your code should run,

```
 sc = SparkContext("yarn", "Simple App")
 spark = SQLContext(sc)
 spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('CHECK')
```

since spark got initialized with `SparkSession`

```
spark = SparkSession.Builder.master('yarn').appName('Check_Con').getOrCreate()
```

Reference : [Spark runs on Yarn cluster exitCode=13:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535411/spark-runs-on-yarn-cluster-exitcode-13)

**Edit 1:**
please run the below snippet with your aws credentials to connect to snowflake.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE = 'net.snowflake.spark.snowflake'

def get_records(spark):
    sfOptions = {
        'sfURL' : 'url',
        'sfAccount' : 'acntname',
        'sfUser' : 'username',
        'sfPassword' : 'pwd',
        'sfRole' : 'role',
        'sfDatabase' : 'dbname',
        'sfSchema' : 'schema',
        'sfWarehouse' : 'warehousename'
    }
    rec_df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE).options(**sfOptions).option('query','select AREA from SCHEMA.TABLENAME limit 1').load()
    rec_df.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').appName('Check_Con').getOrCreate()
        get_records(spark)
```

Comment: I commented the code you mentioned also removed master('yarn') from the code since I am setting it on spark-submit. But I still see the same exception. I have posted the code after implementing your suggestions.

Comment: I have added Edit 1 to my code implementing your suggestions. Any idea after that ?

Comment: please run the code I have added in the answer(fixed some syntax errors in the code).

Comment: Ok, In the first scenario, I have removed the lines and ran the code. It failed again. After that 1. I added master('yarn') to the code but removed it from spark-submit command, ran it, the code failed. 2. Removed master('yarn') from code but added it to spark-submit command and ran it. failed again. 
Should I pass any `config` files or path of any environment variables or files in the spark-submit ?

Comment: 1. are you using kerberos? 2.from where you are running the driver program (EMR or spark cluster?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-snowflake.py", line 24, in <module>
    get_records(spark)
  File "python-snowflake.py", line 19, in get_records
    rec_df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE).options(**sfOptions).options('query','select AREA from SCHEMA.TABLENAME limit 1').load()
TypeError: options() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218109/discussion-between-smart-coder-and-metadata).

Comment: @Metadata , i found another issue and fixed it (added the updated code in the edit 1 section). issue is -?`spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE).options(**sfOptions).options('query','select AREA from SCHEMA.TABLENAME limit 1').load()` should be `spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_DATA_SOURCE).options(**sfOptions).option('query','select AREA from SCHEMA.TABLENAME limit 1').load()`. I found a mismatch in `options().options()` inistead of `options().option()`. could you please run now?